# How to create a version of every possible sentence using an array of each available words?

Tags: javascript

I've been wrapping my head around this for a while, the solution needs to be written in JS.

I need to make every possible sentence based on an array of options for each word, will explain in detail below:

```
Hello | my | name | is | John
```

Is the main sentence I will base this example off, each word in the sentence has a dynamic array of other words that could take their space.

```
let firstWord = ["Hello", "Hi", "Howdy"];
let secondWord = ["my", "your"];
let thirdWord = ["name"];
let fourthWord = ["is", "isn't"];
let fifthWord = ["John"];
```

I tried to find out the number of possible sentences by multiplying each array length, then iterating through the arrays to fill it out but can not grasp the iteration method I need to do this.

How could I solve this?

Comment: This is called a cartesian product. Write a loop for each word position -- first is outer, fifth is innermost, and in the inside of all the loops, that's one result.

Comment: Oh awesome, thanks will check this out!

Comment: Here's a trivial example if the arrays are fixed: `[1,2,3].flatMap(x => [4,5,6].flatMap(y => [7,8,9].map(z => [x, y, z])))`. Replace the arrays with your arrays and add more layers of loops. If you don't know how many words, use the link answers.

Comment: Arrays are all very dynamic, with any number of words in a sentence and any number of options for each word.